# Carousel_Slider won't go back to initial page on data change

Tags: flutter, slider, carousel

I'm working with a carousel_slider on a flutter project and I essentially am loading data for the user to see and giving them the ability to swipe through various pages of content and information.  The user then clicks a button and new data is loaded into the view.  The issue I'm having is that I want the slider to default back to the initial page anytime that the data changes.  Currently, if the user is on page 2 then the data will change for that page, but they have to swipe in order to get back to page 0.  Is there a way to override the slider and tell it to jump back to page 0 when I have a changeState to update the data being shown?  From what I've seen in the carousel_slider library there doesn't seem to be anything documented that would achieve this, and I haven't seen any other discussions or questions on this anywhere.  Code is below for my slider.

```
return CarouselSlider(
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: height,
              initialPage: 0,
              viewportFraction: 1.0,
              enlargeCenterPage: false,
              autoPlay: false,
            ),
            items: pageNumbers
                .map((item) => Container(
                      child: Center(child: product(item)),
                    ))
                .toList(),
          );
```

There are a total of 3 different pages I'm working with, with page 0 being the default page that I want to have users jump back to whenever the data changes.

Comment: Do you use setstate in your button function?

Answer (score 3):

This was really dumb of me.  The library actually does reference how to resolve this.  There is a carousel controller field you can set that has a method called jumpToPage().  By calling this method on my controller after setting the state with the new data it does what I want now.